# why rspec delete all records from test db?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

it's normal when rspec to check unit tests .
i run `rspec` found run this commands `TRUNCATE TABLE` to all tables .

if any way to avoid this when run rspec .

because need for example check like auth and some issues also .
when records deleted, this mean can't complete my test .
why not use **factories** because some function need db .

```
 post = Post.find_by_id(post_id)
 return False and return nil if post.nil? || post.is_deleted == 1
```

spec_helper.rb

```
RSpec.configure do |config|

  config.expect_with :rspec do |expectations|

    expectations.include_chain_clauses_in_custom_matcher_descriptions = true
  end

  config.mock_with :rspec do |mocks|

    mocks.verify_partial_doubles = true
  end

end
```

Comment: Look in your `spec_helper`... what is causing that truncation to occur?

Comment: @JakeWorth i update question . please checks

Comment: Do you have a gem installed that cleans the test database? Most projects do truncate the database between test runs, and so I can't remember if it's RSpec's default behavior, but I think that it isn't.

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely normal practice to empty the database before / after each test runs, so the database is intentionally empty when your test runs **apart from the records that you intentionally add**. This prevents each test from being polluted by the setup for other tests.

In the setup for each test you should create any database records you require. The *factory* helps to create db records, mainly by filling in sensible defaults and associated records as required (see also *traits*). If you use factories, or if you don't you'll still need to create the db records within your test file.

If the `post` from above is the only database record you need, and let's make life simple by not using factories and instantiating it as soon as the test file is loaded I would do this =>

```
let!(:post) { Post.create }
```

Which will create a database record for you, and allow you to manipulate and inspect the `post` variable in your tests.